# Efficiently find "isolated" rows in sql

Tags: sql, impala, memory-efficient

Say we have a table with following schema:

```
| ID            | DATE          | VALUE |
| ------------- |:-------------:| -----:|
| 1             | '2016-08-01'  |  1600 |
| 9             | '2016-03-03'  |    12 |
| 1             | '2016-08-21'  |     1 |
| 4             | '2016-09-01'  |     1 |
| ....                ....         .... |
```

How to efficiently find all rows for which table doesn't contain records with same ID in N days after row's DATE?

Simply put, the goal is to find "last action" for each user (there were no actions from the user for **at least** N days after)

Comment: Please show us some sample output from the example table, and also tag with the exact database you are using (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server).

Comment: Need sample output regarding how you require the data.

Comment: Your question is absolutely unclear... [Try to create a MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or a [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com). We need at least: sample data, the expected output and what you've tried so far.

Comment: Question is unclear. Provide the detail about how you want to get the result with some example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`lead`](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/archive/impala/2-x/2-1-x/topics/impala_analytic_functions.html#lead_unique_1) window function. This will perform better than using a *correlated* subquery:

```
select *
from   ( select id, date, value,
                lead(date) over (partition by id order by date) next_date
         from   mytable ) as detail
where  date < date_sub(next_date, 30) or  next_date is null
```

This assumes your date field is a timestamp. If it is a string, then use `datediff`.

Note that the `next_date is null` part ensures that you also get the most recent user record in the result set, as obviously it has no date following that is too soon after.

Comment: I should change `date_sub` to `days_add(next_date, -30)`, right?

Comment: And can I use one more field as ID? 

If I understand correctly, I need something like this:


`select *
from   ( select id, tag, date, value,
                lead(date) over (partition by id, tag order by date) next_date
         from   mytable ) as detail
where  date < days_add(next_date, -30) or  next_date is null`

Comment: `date_sub(next_date, 30)` and `date_add(next_date, -30)` are equivalent. Yes, you can add more fields like that. The `partition by` clause defines the sub-section (group, also called "window") in which you want to compare the dates.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds pretty clear to me :)

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT id 
    FROM mytable t2 
    WHERE 
        t2.date > t1.date AND 
        t2.date < t1.date + '30days'::interval AND 
        t1.id = t2.id
)
```

Of course, you have to match syntax (especially date-related) to your target DB.

Comment: No, it will not. This is not a JOIN. NOT EXISTS will eliminate any existing close-date data, but does not care if you have nothing to search through.